# How do I edit a closed question?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I have a closed question which I would like to edit it in the hope of getting an answer. The FAQ provides no assistance on how I can achieve this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can edit your own questions just fine, even when closed.

Comment: Are you asking for what you need to do to be able to edit the text?  If so, you press the "edit" button.  Any question that's not locked (note that locked is different from closed) can be edited.  If you're asking what edits you need to make to make the question good, we'll need to see the question.

Answer (score 2):

Open the question - at the bottom of the question are some options. One of the options is `'edit'`. You can use that. However I can't see any StackExchange account that you have other than this Meta one. Do you have a separate account elsewhere?

If you don't have an account on those sites you won't have the ability to edit, but you will see a link saying `'Improve this Question'` that will allow you to make an edit.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I mostly use a different computer and that is where the question was sent from. I could not see either the edit or improve question until I loged in with those details.